# JList in Java I Dont know where to start

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Hi this is my code in Java it is  just a simple program that shows a frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TelikiErgasia extends JFrame {

  public TelikiErgasia(){
    setSize(700,700);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TelikiErgasia();
  }

}
```

I want to make a jlist but every time i try i fail...i cannot declare a private jlist inside public class TelikiErgasia why?Can you show me a way to make a jlist?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Here is documentation and an example of Jlist in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search can fetch you 1000's of examples :

See the following :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm

http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jlist-class-example

Comment: @user3014391 Play around with these examples. And if you don't get further...ask again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To add the JList I am attaching the below code:

```
public class TelikiErgasia extends JFrame {

private JList list;



public TelikiErgasia(){

setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
list = new JList(new Object[]{"INDIA", "AMERICA", "AUSTRALIA", "JAPAN"});

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);


add(list);
setSize(700,700);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TelikiErgasia();
  }

}
```

This will just add JList on the JFrame at the left top corner.
To understand the Swing basics use the attached links:  [Swing Basics](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)